# There is no field with exactly 6 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I saw the related posts, and I tried a different proof. Please have a look.

Let $D$ be any field with $|D|=6$.

$|D|=6<\infty \Longrightarrow Char(D)\neq 0\Longrightarrow Char(D)=prime\ number$

From the theorem of Lagrange in $(D,+)$ we have that:
$$ord(1_R) \mid  |D| \Longrightarrow Char(D)\mid  |D|\Longrightarrow Char(D)\mid 6$$
So, $Char(D)=2$ or $3$.

- $Char(D)=2$

$\forall x\in U(D):ord(x)=Char(D) \Longrightarrow ord(x)=2 \Longrightarrow 2x=0_D \Longrightarrow x=-x $ (*)

If $H= \{0_D, a,b,a+b\} $ from (*) $(H,+)\leq (D,+)$ and from Theorem Of Lagrange we have that $|H|\mid |D| \Longrightarrow4|6$, contradiction.

- $Char(D)=3$

Can we find another additive subgroup of $(D,+)$ with 4 or 5 elements to work on the same say as above?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof using your idea of looking at the additive group of $D$.

Since the additive group of $D$ is abelian and has order $6$, it must be $C_6$.

Let $g$ be a generator for the additive group of $D$, that is, an element of additive order $6$.

Then $0 = 6 \cdot g = (2 \cdot 1_D)(3 \cdot g)$. Since $3 \cdot g \ne 0$, we must gave $2 \cdot 1_D=0$ because $D$ is a domain.

In the same manner, $0 = 6 \cdot g = (3 \cdot 1_D)(2 \cdot g)$ implies $3 \cdot 1_D=0$.

But then $1_D = 3 \cdot 1_D - 2 \cdot 1_D = 0$ and $D$ is the zero ring.

Comment: Why $(D,+)$ = additive group with$ |D|=6$ implies that is $C_6$? And also we didn find an additive subgroup $H'$ of $D$ such that $|H'|\nmid |D|$

Comment: @Chris, there are only two groups of order $6$: $S_3$ and $C_6$.